# How to change generated files output path in Docpad?

Tags: docpad

I want to do something like what [docpad-plugin-dateurls](https://github.com/mgroves84/docpad-plugin-dateurls) does but in the context of static site generation.

I need, for example, to map the file `/src/documents/posts/2013-09-10-post-title.html` to the url `http://localhost:9778/posts/2013/09/10/post-title.html`

Which would be the best approach to acomplish this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally implemented this by setting the `outPath` of each document in the `renderBefore` event.
See here: https://github.com/gschuager/blog/blob/7451fbcb829ad93154d24b281c7e8e30d3a0edac/docpad.js#L83

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this: https://github.com/Greduan/eduantech.docpad/blob/d5e97638331ab24730d3331b9fbcc30cf1d46dcc/docpad.coffee#L45-L49

You would modify it for your needs but it does what you need I think. :)

Comment: Well, the idea makes sense, but for some reason it didn't work for me

Comment: @Alex did you modify it or did you copy it as-is?

Comment: @Alex BTW, figured out recently, this requires the Node.js server to be active and for DocPad to be running. Opened an issue on how this could be fixed https://github.com/bevry/docpad/issues/648

Comment: Well, that makes sense, as I was using just the generate function. Thanks for DocPad and community support ;)

Comment: Thank you, but as noted, this requires a node server to handle routing. See my other answer for a static way of doing this.