# Docpad: source documents in one dir but output should go into subdirs based on attribute value

Tags: docpad

I'm total beginner with docpad.

I want to have a documents files like this:

- 20131120-sometitle-EN.html.md
- 20131120-sometitle-CS.html.md

I want to have it like this as I want to have quick overview if I have translation of a document into another language.

Each of this document would have attribute '`lang`' set. Maybe I could just take language code from filename but right now I'd like to use '`lang`' attribute. So...:

- 20131120-sometitle-EN.html.md with 'lang: en'
- 20131120-sometitle-CS.html.md with 'lang: cs'

I would like to have each document generated into a subdir based on value in '`lang`' attribute. Thus one with '`lang: en`' should go into subdir '`en`', other one into subdir '`cs`'.

Could anybody direct me how I could do it?

Answer (score 0):

This previous answer may help you :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19185599/232943

In your docpad.coffee configuration file, add an events key with a renderBefore inside.

It means that this action will be triggered during the generation process.
Loop through all your documents, check for the lang attribute and reset the outPut path value.